# Python calling mutiple URLs and pulling data from them

Tags: python, url, call, taxonomy, genetics

I'm trying to write a script that will call up a webpage (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?mode=Tree&id=7742&lvl=3&lin=f&keep=1&srchmode=1&unlock), scan it, and then pull out the orders, families, genera, and species within each nested taxonomic group. However, I only want the vertebrates (a very small section of the entire website) but the URLs associated with the various vertebrate taxa are not in any discernible pattern (i.e. sequential). Is there a way to do this reasonable? I've been having a lot of problems trying to formulate different ways to accomplish this goal.

Comment: This is called **web-scraping** and there are many prior Q&A on this (500 alone of them tagged Python). In Python, _twill_ is a useability layer which sits on top of _mechanize_ (for the automation); and _BeautifulSoup_ for the actual scraping.

Comment: [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/commands.html) specifically makes following links easier than plain mechanize, specifically its [follow](http://twill.idyll.org/commands.html) command works by link title (rather than URL). If this doesn't solve your question, show us some sample html snippet of these links?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear (at least, to me) what do you exactly want to do, but, for what I understood, you need to create some sort of crawler that looks for links in the pages, navigate the site and categorize them?

If so, go for [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), that allows you to emulate a web browser, and navigate along the site, easily extracting and following links, submitting forms, etc. etc.